# Why are these hints (tooltips) missing the bottom?

Tags: 16.04, gnome

In the below screenshots, you can see the hints (tooltips) are white on the bottom, where they should be black.

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

I just installed Ubuntu and I have no idea what to do.

Comment: I'm not sure, but try restarting, and maybe try installing/updating graphics drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing on a fresh install of 16.04.3 64bit on a Sony Vaio E Series.

High contrast theme does not exhibit this fault.  Affects Radiance and Ambiance themes.

Not an issue on a lenovo think pad T410.